# Drawing nodes with coordinates in correct position using NetworkX/Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, networkx

I know that x/y-axis are flipped (Berlin is south-east of Hamburg), but do I need to fix this manually or can matplotlib/networkx do this for me? And if that needs to be done manually, is there a best way to do it?

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_node('Hamburg', pos=(53.5672, 10.0285))
G.add_node('Berlin', pos=(52.51704, 13.38792))

nx.draw(G, nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos'), with_labels=True, node_size=0)
```

[image]

Comment: I think your deeper issue is that you're treating latitude as "x" and longitude as "y".   Instead, <x,y> is <long,lat>.  Inverting the x and y axes won't change that.  Instead, you'll need to plot `long, lat` instead of `lat, long`.

Comment: For the general case, use the `pos` argument in `nx.draw`, see [Plot NetworkX Graph with coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63009048/9698684)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

pyplot.gca().invert_yaxis()
pyplot.gca().invert_xaxis()
```

Comment: Okay, that is brilliant, because now I know that lat/lon had to be flipped. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you can invert the positions before plotting.

```
pos = {city:(long, lat) for (city, (lat,long)) in nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos').items()}
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, node_size=0)
```

What the command does is it takes the dictionary `nx.get_node_attributes('pos')` and finds all the items.  An item looks like `(city, (lat, long))`, so it reads in each item in that format and then creates an entry in the new dictionary `pos` so that `pos[city]=(long,lat)`.