# Plot NetworkX Graph with coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

My networkx graph consists of objects that have property named "coords" (x,y) :

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class device():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.coords = (0,0)
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

device1 =  device('1')
device1.coords = (20, 5)
device2 =  device('2')
device2.coords = (-4, 10.5)
device3 =  device('3')
device3.coords = (17, -5)

G = nx.Graph() 
G.add_nodes_from([device1, device2, device3])
nx.draw(G, with_labels = True)
plt.show()
```

Any time when I plot it matplotlib draws graph in a chaotic order.
How to plot such a graph according to coordinates?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`nx.draw`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.html#draw) takes a `pos` parameter to position all nodes. It expects a dictionary with nodes as keys and positions as values. So you could change the above to:

```
devices = [device1, device2, device3]
G = nx.Graph() 
G.add_nodes_from(devices)

pos = {dev:dev.coords for dev in devices}
# {1: (20, 5), 2: (-4, 10.5), 3: (17, -5)}
nx.draw(G, pos=pos, with_labels = True, node_color='lightblue')
plt.show()
```

[image]